# postgres criteriaQuery with orderBy in sum

Tags: postgresql, jpa, sum, sql-order-by, criteriaquery

I'm trying to build this postgres query snippet with criteriaQuery:

```
select
    sum (attr order by attr2)
```

The problem is that because of floating point precision the order of the attr2 values is important in summation. Do you have an idea how to build this with criteriaBuilder?

I made it work with a custom pgDialect function:

```
    registerFunction("sum_order_by", new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.FLOAT, "sum(?1 order by ?2)"));
```

```
                Expression<Float> functionSumOrderByAttr2 = criteriaBuilder.function( "sum_order_by", Float.class,
                        root.get( "attr2" ).as( Float.class ),
                        criteriaBuilder.parameter( String.class, "orderBy") );
```

Is there an inherent way of doing this with criteriaQuery?